# NSURL from NSURLConnection?

Tags: cocoa, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

It seems dead simple, as to create an `NSURLConnection` I usually do this:

```
NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

But how can I get the URL back in the delegate methods? Short of hanging on to them myself (I'm running many connections at once, so this becomes slightly messy). It seems as though I should be able to get the URL back from a connection.

Am I missing something?

Comment: did you ever figured it out to get url in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` with `NSURLConnection` object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In -connection:didReceiveResponse: you can get the URL.  Note that this may not be the same URL you created the connection with since the connection may have been redirected.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
            didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSURL * url = [response URL]; // The URL
}
```

Comment: thats ok for showing initialization, but how to know which connection finished first from -   (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but it sounds like you're using a single delegate for multiple connections. I don't recommend that since you'll often set instance variables based on the responses and data received in the delegate methods. You should probably create a class for the sole purpose of being a delegate and instantiate a new one for each connection.